# How To fetch a user's AD groups in login form authenticator | Symfony

Tags: azure-active-directory, symfony6, authenticator

Using symfony `LoginFormAuthenticator`, how to fetch azure user's groups in TODO section.
Note that fetching AD groups that azure user belongs to needs SSO auth, but I don't want passing by that process, only fetching user's groups. Any idea?

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
  use TargetPathTrait;

  public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'login';

  private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator;

  public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
  {
      $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
  }

  /**
   * @inheritDoc
   * @param Request $request
   * @return bool
   */
  public function supports(Request $request): bool
  {
      return $request->isMethod('POST') && $request->attributes->get('_route') === self::LOGIN_ROUTE;
  }

  /**
   * @inheritDoc
   * @param Request $request
   * @return Passport
   */
  public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
  {
      $aufUsername = $request->request->get('_username', '');

      $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $aufUsername);

      return new Passport(
          new UserBadge($aufUsername, function() use ($aufUsername) {
            // TODO
            // fetch a AD user with email $aufUsername and then get AD groups he belongs to
          }),
          new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('_password', '')),
          [
              new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->request->get('_csrf_token')),
          ]
      );
  }

  /**
   * @inheritDoc
   * @param Request $request
   * @param TokenInterface $token
   * @param string $firewallName
   * @return Response|null
   */
   public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
  {
      if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
          return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
      }

       return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('homepage'));
  }

  /**
   * @inheritDoc
   * @param Request $request
   * @return string
   */
  protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
  {
      return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
  }
}
```